# I want to do validation in controller to check if value == null save the old value with looping

Tags: java, spring-boot

```
here is my service method 


public Employee updateByEmployeeIdAndFirstName(Long employeeId, String firstName, Employee employeesDetails){
        Employee updateEmployee = employeeRepository.findByEmployeeIdAndFirstName(employeeId, firstName).get(0);
        if (employeesDetails.getFirstName() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setFirstName(employeesDetails.getFirstName());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getLastName() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setLastName(employeesDetails.getLastName());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getEmail() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setEmail(employeesDetails.getEmail());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getPhoneNumber() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setPhoneNumber(employeesDetails.getPhoneNumber());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getHireDate() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setHireDate(employeesDetails.getHireDate());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getJob() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setJob(employeesDetails.getJob());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getSalary() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setSalary(employeesDetails.getSalary());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getCommissionPct() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setCommissionPct(employeesDetails.getCommissionPct());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getManager() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setManager(employeesDetails.getManager());
        }
        if (employeesDetails.getDepartment() != null ) {
            updateEmployee.setDepartment(employeesDetails.getDepartment());
        }
        employeeRepository.save(updateEmployee);
        return updateEmployee;
    }

here is my mapping method
```

@PutMapping(path = "/update")
public ResponseEntity updateEmployee(@RequestParam("id") Long employeeId, @RequestParam("firstName") String firstName, @RequestBody Employee employeesDetails) {
return ResponseEntity.ok(employeeService.updateByEmployeeIdAndFirstName(employeeId, firstName, employeesDetails));
}

i want to make my update method more flexible with looping so no need to use a lot of if

Comment: Hi, you can have a look at `org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils#copyProperties(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object, java.lang.Class<?>, java.lang.String...)` method and write something similar but with a value null check.

Comment: Why are you null checking?  Why not just pass through the null?

Answer (score 1):

It's not the looping solution, but you can also remove ifs with Optional, for example:

```
Optional.ofNullable(employeesDetails.getEmail()).ifPresent(updateEmployee::setEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

If any fields need to be assigned, i think you can use reflection

```
    Field[] fields = employeesDetails.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (int i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        fields[i].setAccessible(true);
        Object value = fields[i].get(employeesDetails);
        fields[i].set(updateEmployee, value);
        System.out.println(fields[i].get(updateEmployee));
    }
```